# VS Code "terminal.integrated.env.osx"

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

On VS Code, with python extension, I am trying to achieve a very basic thing : add the workspace directory to the python path, when running the code in the integrated terminal.

From reading the [doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments), the only thing I'd have to do is add this line to the workspace's `setting.json` file :

```
"terminal.integrated.env.osx": {
        "PYTHONPATH": "/path_to_workspace_dir/"
    }
```

However, this does not work.
Trying to dig into it, I noticed the following:

- Adding this to the *Users's* settings does work.
- Adding *other* environment variables to the workspace's settings does work
- So only the `PYTHONPATH`'s variable of the workspace's settings does not work

How can I fix that issue?